# cassandra: `sstabledump` output questions

Tags: cassandra, nosql

I'm inspecting the output of `sstabledump`, to gain better understanding of the cassandra data model, and I have some questions

From the output of of `sstabledump` it seems that

1. a table is a list of partitions (split by partition key)
2. a partition is a list of rows (split according to clustering key)
3. a row is a map of key-value pairs, where the keys belong in a predefined list

Question 1: For each partition, as well as for each row inside a partition, there is a `position` key. What does this value correspond to? Physical storage details? And how exactly?

Question 2: Each row inside each partition has a `type: row` key-value pair. Could this type be anything else? If yes, what? If not

- why have a value that is always the same?
- why is cassandra is classified as wide-column and other similar terms? Looks more like a two-level row storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partition key is the murmur3 hash of whatever you assigned as the primary key. [Consistent hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_hashing) is used with that hash to determine which node in the cluster that partition belongs to and its replicas. Within each partition data is sorted by clustering key, and then by cell name within the row. The structure is used so redundant things like timestamps if inserted for a row at once is only inserted once as a vint delta sequence from the partitions to save space.

On disk the partitions are sorted in order of this hashed key. The output of the `position` key is just referring to where in the sstable's data file its located (decompressed byte offset). `type` can also identify in that spot as a static block, which is located at the beginning of each partition for any static cells or a ranged tombstone marker (beginning or end). Note that values are sometimes for sstabledump repeated in json for readability even if not physically written on disk (ie repeated timestamps).

You can have many of these rows inside a partition, a common datamodel for time series for example is to use timestamp as the clustering key which makes very wide partitions with millions of rows. Pre 3.0 as well the data storage was closer to [big table](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//archive/bigtable-osdi06.pdf)'s design. It was essentially a `Map<byte[], SortedMap<byte[], Cell>>` where the Comparator of the sorted map was changed based on schema. It did not differentiate rows and columns within a partition, and it lead to massive amounts redundant data and was redesigned to fit the query language better.

Some more references:

- Explanation of motivation of 3.0 change by DataStax [here](https://www.datastax.com/2015/12/storage-engine-30)
- [Blog post by TLP](http://thelastpickle.com/blog/2016/03/04/introductiont-to-the-apache-cassandra-3-storage-engine.html) has a good detailed explanation of the new disk format
- [CASSANDRA-8099](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-8099)

Comment: So, `"type": "row"` is a leftover from earlier versions? there are not other `"type"` values?

Comment: other types are `static_block`, `range_tombstone_bound`, and `range_tombstone_boundary`

Comment: @ChrisLohfink Are these documented somewhere? Specifically I'd like to understand `range_tombstone_bound` and `range_tombstone_boundary` a bit better.

Comment: not currently no, the storage engine representation is kinda an internal detail that can change from version to version (ie it was completely rewritten in 3.0 but mostly was invisible from a query and schema level perspective). Tombstones have changed a lot but the behavior is the same, just range tombstones became more efficient.